# Why does $^{-1}$ placed in front of many operations mean its inverse?

Tags: notation, soft-question, intuition

Is there a particular reason why functions, trigonometric operations, and matrices (e.g. $f^{-1}$, $\sin^{-1}$, $A^{-1}$) use a superscript negative-one to indicate the inverse? Trig operations can use alternatively an $a$ or longer version $\operatorname{arc}$  right before it to mean the same thing as the as $^{-1}$ right after it, but in the other cases I've only seen the superscript -1 used.  Is there is a logical, intuitive, historical, or otherwise sensical reason for it?

Answer (score 5):

The idea is that, for example, $f^6(x)$ means $f(f(f(f(f(f(x)))))),$ so the superscript indicates how many times the operation is applied.

Comment: To add to this answer, we have $f^n (f^m (x)) = f^{n + m}(x)$ for all natural numbers $n, m$. We want to make sense of $f^k (x)$ for integer $k$, and we want $f^n (f^m (x)) = f^{n + m}(x)$ for all integers $n, m$. To start, we set $f^0 (x) = x$. Then you can check that we should have $f(f^{-1}(x)) = f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^0 (x) = x$. This calculation shows that $f^{-1}$ really should play the role of an inverse for $f$. We make it so by definition.

Comment: But $\cos^2x=(\cos x)^2,$ not $\cos\cos x,$ and $\cos^{-1} x$ is still the inverse function. There is an inconsistency between our notations.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews  That may be one reason why in the case of trig functions the superscript notations are less favored than in other places such as functions. I for one dislike the 2 superscript meaning the operand getting squared (instead of something unto the actual operation), feels like a hacky shortcut, inconsistent with the -1 since that doesn't mean the multiplicative inverse of the operand.

Comment: @whatyeodds : You're in excellent company: Carl Gauss disliked that usage for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might also stem from the way we denote a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{R}.$ Heuristically, we may think of the composition of two functions as a sort of product, so if you have a function $f,$ you may simplify $f f^{-1} = f \frac{1}{f} = 1,$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity of this product, i.e. the identity map. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, likely borrowed from the multiplicative inverse of real numbers when identity and inverses were discovered in other areas analogous to those for multiplication. Sticking it at the end of the function name but before parenthesis containing variables was an (arguably insufficient) way of distinguishing $f^{-1}$ from $\frac{1}{f}$. For trig functions this is unfortunately subverted by the the practice of using this space to indicate exponents, which seems to be mostly a way of cutting down on parenthesis? So people came up with $\sec$ and $\arccos$.

Answer (score 1):

It is inconsistent. We write $\cos^2 x$ for $(\cos x)^2$ but $\cos^{-1} x$ is the inverse function, rather than $(\cos x)^{-1}.$

This is probably because we have a name $\sec x=(\cos x)^{-1}$ and we rarely ever need to apply $\cos\cos x.$

I’ve never seen anybody use $\cos^{-2}x,$ but if I did, and there was no specific meaning, I’d take it to mean $(\cos x)^{-2}.$

While in some cases $f^n=f\circ f\circ \cdots\circ f$ might make sense, in a lot of cases it does.

So this is a case where we use inconsistent notation because it is more convenient, and we have other notations if we want.

So $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function, and we write $1/f$ explicitly for the other meaning.

And $f^n(x)=(f(x))^n$ when that makes sense, so we are stuck writing $f^{\circ n}$ for repeated composition.

---

For linear transformations, and hence matrices, $A$, it doesn’t make sense to take $(Av)^n,$ in general, so $A^n$ is always defined as composition, so there is no inconsistency in that case.